# C# - Create a 3D list of integer index with values (similar to arrays)

Tags: c#, arrays, list, multidimensional-array, position

basically what I'm trying to do is have a way to store a value at a certain 3D position and be able to access it. So, for example, I would store the value of 3 at position (4, 5, 6), then I would later tell my program to recall the value at (4, 5, 6) and it would return a 3.

I believe (but could be very wrong) that I'd start by creating the list with something like this:

```
public static IList<IList<IList<int>>> valueList = new List<List<List<int>>>();
```

But I have no idea how I would store or access items in the list.

I want something similar to an array, but I don't think I want to use arrays because the positions have the possibility of being negative and there shouldn't be a minimum or maximum position in the list.

Please let me know if either you know how to do this or you know of an alternative method for accomplishing this goal, as I have little clue as to what I'm doing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are modeling three dimensional space.  You could create a class that represent 3D coordinates.  You could use an instance of this class as a key in a dictionary to store an object.  A simplified starting point might look like:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Vector
{
    public int X {get; set;}
    public int Y {get; set;}
    public int Z {get; set;}    
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<Vector, int> map = new Dictionary<Vector, int>();

        var vector = new Vector() { X = 4, Y = 5, Z = 6 };
        map.Add(vector, 3);

        int result = 0;
        if (map.Keys.Contains(vector))
        {
            result = map[vector];
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

You will need to check that the dictionary contains your key before using it.  You might want to use doubles instead of ints.  And you might want to override the equality operator and hash function to compare equivalent Vectors.

Comment: Wouldn't this run slowly if there are lots of items in the list? I am expecting to have possibly billions of items (things would add up quickly, a 1000x1000x1000 cube is 1 billion items).

Comment: @AaronFranke Thinking o storing a billion of anything in memory is a non  starter to begin with, you better rethink your whole approach.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed, and I've decided I will avoid billions of things at whatever cost. I've split up my grid into a dictionary of 16x16x16 chunks to split up the time required to process it all. I've even limited the coordinates to `short`s rather than `int`s to restrict the size. I ended up calling the class Point3 which is created similar to Unity's Vector3. I might finish adding all of Vector3's methods and publish it some day.